# How to fetch internal links from a webpage?

Tags: php, parsing, dom, xpath, html-parsing

I use `XPath` to parse a HTML webpage for fetching all internal links. `DOMXPath` will return all links provided in `href`. How can I separate internal an external links?

I introduce a series of string checks to remove external links; but the problem is that there are different ways to link internal pages such as

```
    page.html
    /page.html
    http://domain.com/page.html
    http://subdomain.domain.com/page.html
    ....
```

What is the safest way to distinguish internal links (any link to the present domain including its subdomains) and external links (to any other domain).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to see if the first 4 characters are http.

If so, use the [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function to check whether the host is the same.
If not, it's internal.

Comment: The list provided by DOM is not necessarily full urls. It may simple return `/page.html` as given in the example.

Comment: Actually no, as `host` in `parse_url()` cannot recognize domain/subdomain. Probably it cannot be resolved, as there is no function in PHP to detect `subdomain`.

Comment: What exactly do you want, would you define internal as being on the same domain or being on the same subdomain?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a small example i have written using preg_match. Let me know if it helps.

```
<?php
function get_a_href($url){
    $url = htmlentities(strip_tags($url));
    $ExplodeUrlInArray = explode('/',$url);
    $DomainName = $ExplodeUrlInArray[2];
    $file = @file_get_contents($url);
    $h1count = preg_match_all('/(href=["|\'])(.*?)(["|\'])/i',$file,$patterns);
    $linksInArray = $patterns[2];
    $CountOfLinks = count($linksInArray);
    $InternalLinkCount = 0;
    $ExternalLinkCount = 0;
    for($Counter=0;$Counter<$CountOfLinks;$Counter++){
     if($linksInArray[$Counter] == "" || $linksInArray[$Counter] == "#")
      continue;
    preg_match('/javascript:/', $linksInArray[$Counter],$CheckJavascriptLink);
    if($CheckJavascriptLink != NULL)
    continue;
    $Link = $linksInArray[$Counter];
    preg_match('/\?/', $linksInArray[$Counter],$CheckForArgumentsInUrl);
    if($CheckForArgumentsInUrl != NULL)
    {
    $ExplodeLink = explode('?',$linksInArray[$Counter]);
    $Link = $ExplodeLink[0];
    }
    preg_match('/'.$DomainName.'/',$Link,$Check);
    if($Check == NULL)
    {
    preg_match('/http:\/\//',$Link,$ExternalLinkCheck);
    if($ExternalLinkCheck == NULL)
    {
    $InternalDomainsInArray[$InternalLinkCount] = $Link;
    $InternalLinkCount++;
    }
    else
    {
    $ExternalDomainsInArray[$ExternalLinkCount] = $Link;
    $ExternalLinkCount++;
    }
    }
    else
    {
    $InternalDomainsInArray[$InternalLinkCount] = $Link;
    $InternalLinkCount++;
    }
    }
    $LinksResultsInArray = array(
    'ExternalLinks'=>$ExternalDomainsInArray,
    'InternalLinks'=>$InternalDomainsInArray
    );
    return $LinksResultsInArray;
    }
    ?>
```